# SwiftUI List Header Alignment on iOS 15?

Tags: swiftui, ios15

With the following code on iOS 15, the header text is aligned with the text within the List:

```
List {
    Section {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    } header: {
        Text("Section Header").sectionHeaderStyle()
    }
}
.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())

//...

public extension Text {
    func sectionHeaderStyle() -> some View {
        self
            .font(.system(.title3))
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
            .textCase(nil)
    }
}
```

[image: List Header alignment on iOS 15]

However, back on iOS 14, the analogous code aligns the header with the List Section itself:

```
List {
    Section(header: Text("Section Header").sectionHeaderStyle()) {
        Text("Hello, world!")
    }
}
.listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
```

[image: List Header alignment on iOS 14]

Does anyone know how to get the iOS 14 behavior of aligning the section header with the List Section itself, and not aligning with the text within the Section?

Comment: Maybe try a hardcoded `offSet`... or just go with it. Fighting against SwiftUI design changes is very tedious.

Comment: Undoubtedly - I'm hoping there's an obvious new modifier I'm unaware of. It's particularly odd since this year the prominentInsetGroupedHeader was introduced on the UIKit side, making it easier to get this look in UIKit but harder to get this look in SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilistcontentconfiguration/3752759-prominentinsetgroupedheader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question, someone graciously pointed me to the [headerProminence(.increased)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/headerprominence%28_:%29) modifier that does what I want here.